# Update @Html.Partial() View only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, controller, partial-page-refresh

I am not looking for a javascript/jquery answer.  I can do that, but I feel like it breaks the purpose.  This seems like something that should be possible without javascript.

I'm trying to get a simple listbox selection to update an @Html.Partial section, and I'm not exactly sure what to do.  Everything loads initially just fine.  After I submit, however, I am not quite sure how to 'attach' to my partial view to update it.

The purpose here is to only load the listbox one time, and let them view or request as many new reports as they want without reloading.  If it's not possible, that's fine, I can use one page, reload the listboxes, and it will work.  I just don't see why I would need to go to the database to reload the listbox items every time they view or request a report.

"master" html page:

```
@using TCTReports.Models
@model ReportViewModel
<h2>My Reports</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Select Report</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetReport", "Report"))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMyID, Model.myLB)
       <input type="submit" value="View" />
    }      
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>All Reports</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ReqReport", "Report"))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAllID, Model.allLB)
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    }
</div>
</div>
@Html.Partial("_Msg")
```

_Msg is super simple atm.  It would eventually be a report viewer, for now, it looks at @Viewbag...

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
```

Controller submit actions (I get my selected value just fine.  currently on void but was ActionResult with Views - but I don't feel like that is correct either, as it completely overwrites the page (even with PartialView) and I lose my listboxes and _layout...):

```
public void GetReport(ReportViewModel model)
    {
        var myID = model.SelectedMyID;            
        ViewBag.Message = "Report: " + myID.ToString() + " Selected.";
        //return PartialView("_Msg","Test");
    }
    public void ReqReport(ReportViewModel model)
    {
        var allID = model.SelectedAllID;
        ViewBag.Message = "Report: " + allID.ToString() + " Requested.";
        //return PartialView("_Msg", "Test");
    }
```

Ok, so how would I go about updating _Msg and refreshing only the @Html.PartialView() section of my master html page?  I played with @sections briefly but didn't make much progress.

Comment: I just let it reload the listbox for now.  If someone comes along with an answer I'll revisit.  It works, I just don't see a need for constant dataaccess.

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be save the Data Source for the List Box to Session or hard code it if the List Box's Data Source remains static.  Also, using JavaScript to reload the List Box isn't that bad.  Using a combination of Ajax and Session would make it simple.

Comment: Unless you use ajax to update the element containing the partial view (not clear why you do not want to do that), then you method needs to be an `ActionResult` and return the whole view (including the html for the dropdownlists)

Comment: That's what I did Stephen.  Just reload the whole page.